# Limit of $(u_n)$ defined by $u_{n+2}=\frac{u_{n+1}^2 + u_n^2}{u_{n+1} + u_n}$ with $u_1>u_0>0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

> Let $(u_n)$ such that $u_0=a$, $u_1=b$, with $0<a<b$, and $$u_{n+2}=\dfrac{u_{n+1}^2 + u_n^2}{u_{n+1} + u_n}$$
>   Study the convergence of $(u_n)$.

I have no idea about how to start...Tried $u_{n+1}-u_n, \dfrac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}$, but I didn't find anything interesting (but maybe I'm wrong).

Comment: First step: Can you show that $$\min\{u_{n+1},u_n\}\leqslant u_{n+2}\leqslant\max\{u_{n+1},u_n\}$$ for every $n$?

Comment: I can't show it... How do you?

Comment: What did you try to show one of the inequalities in my comment?

Comment: Oh, yeah I finally did it! Just had to test $u_n - min\{u_{n+1},u_n\}$ and the other difference. I've shown it, (so $\forall n\geqslant 2, a\leqslant u_n\leqslant b$, but I don't know if it's useful...). But I still don't get it. What can I do next?

Comment: Now knowing that $(u_n)$ is bounded in $[a, b]$, what can you read out from the following computation? $$ |u_{n+2} - u_{n+1}| = \frac{u_n}{u_{n+1} + u_n} |u_{n+1} - u_n| $$

Comment: $|u_{n+2}-u_{n+1}|\leqslant \dfrac{b}{2a}|u_{n+1}-u_n|$ ?

Comment: @MiKiDe it is very usefull the fact that ,you proved that $a \leq u_n \leq b$ for $n \geq 2$..Using now the inequality in your last comment you can prove that $u_n$ is a Cauchy sequece thus converges

Comment: @MariosGretsas I understand but it's possible to show it only if b/2a<1, isn't it?

Comment: Oh yes indeed...i thought  it was  $b<a$ and not the other way around.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably it is a good time to give a full solution.

1. Write the recurrence relation as

   $$ u_{n+2} = (1 - \lambda_n) u_{n+1} + \lambda_n u_n, \qquad \lambda_n = \frac{u_n}{u_n + u_{n+1}} $$

   Using this inductively, we find that

   $$\min\{u_n, u_{n+1}\} \leq u_{n+2} \leq \max\{u_n, u_{n+1}\}.$$

   In particular, $u_n \in [a, b]$ for all $n$.
2. Now from the above formula, we also know that

   $$ |u_{n+2} - u_{n+1}| = \lambda_n |u_{n+1} - u_n|. $$

   But since $u_{n+1}/u_n \geq a/b$, we have

   $$ \lambda_n = \frac{1}{\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n} + 1} \leq \frac{1}{\frac{a}{b} + 1}  < 1. $$

   This tells that $(u_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence and hence converges.